# How to test Google Place API Third Party Attributions

Tags: google-places-api

Google Places API rules define that we need to [show third party attributions](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/attributions).

The problem is, I have no idea which address or `Place` will have a third party attribution, so I can test if my UI is behaving as it should. Of course I can mock this kind of data, but I wanted to test with real data also once.

Does anyone knows which address/`Place` has a third party attribution?